# how to make the background image fit to the screen in html without using CSS style sheet

Tags: html

I want to display a video in my local host site using html. In that I like to add a background image sized 748x489. But it is not fit to the screen. I want to fit it to the screen without using any external style sheets, CSS etc. please help me..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title style="color:red"> GOWTHAM </title>

<body background="C:\Users\win7\Desktop\sand.jpg" style="width:1040;height:960;">

<center>
<br>
<video width="640" height="540" controls>
<source src="C:\Users\win7\Desktop\gow.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<h1 style="color:red"> GOWTHAM IN STYLE!!! </h1>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you don't want to use an external stylesheet, thing that I personally discourage, then you have to rely on inline style.

Firstly you'll need to set the size of the `<body>` element then, set his background value. To do it you need to go like

```
<body style="size:1040px;height:960px;background:url('path/to/file.jpg') no-repeat; background-size: cover">
```

Please mind in the example above the presence of `px` which stands for pixel and which you omitted and the presence of the rule `no-repeat` and `background-size: cover` which means that the background will be stretched to cover the whole size of the element. Otherwise if the image is not big enough and / or is part of a repetitive pattern remove both and go like

```
<body style="size:1040px;height:960px;background:url('path/to/file.jpg');">
```

Comment: sorry.. I tried this but it's not working. Moreover background image is not displayed. Instead of displaying the image fit to screen, simply, it displayed  a plain white background. Could you tell me why it is?

Comment: @Sangee I think you're mistaking something, plus I just noticed that in your HTML you don't close the `<head>` tag and put a double `<html>` tag. Moreover you shouldn't give style to the `<title>` tag, since it's not a heading on the page but the actual page's title you can see on your browser/tab. Anyway here you can see a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndreIDK/mcavqw8v/) for the first example (obviously the video is not working) and here a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndreIDK/mcavqw8v/1/) for the second one.

Comment: Thank you sir!!! Now it's WORKING!!!! :-)  one more doubt... I want to repeat the video only for 5 times. How can I give it with '<video controls loop>' ?